# Create rows with specific binding?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to create a result like this:

[image]

but, there is no way in xaml to add rows, only columns, I did:

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Teams"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="1" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="2" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="3" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="4" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="5" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pt." />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

I'm beginner and no solution found so far, idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like instead of two rows you actually have one very tall row; so instead of `DataGridTextColumn` you could do something like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="1">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
              ... Your content goes here
          </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I know this.. I mean the structure of xaml, as you can see the first row binding different element against the second row, and then the third row repeat the structure of the first row and so on...

Comment: @opo Understood; you should clarify that in your question. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what Bradley said, just to extend put your DataTemplate like this

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="1">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/>
 <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Inlines>
            <Run Text="{Binding Path={Binding CurrentTeamPoint}}">
            </Run>
            <Run Text="-">
            </Run>
            <Run Text="{Binding Path={Binding OpponentTeamPoint}}">
            </Run>
        </TextBlock.Inlines>
    </TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Hope this helps.